# Twitter like relationships in JPA

Tags: database, database-design, jpa

I'm getting into problems with JPA. I'm trying to implement a database that allows users to follow other users and be followed.
I think I'd need (summing up) something like this:

```
USER_TABLE: id | userName
RELATIONSHIP_TABLE: id | follower | followed | acceptation
```

I have two entities (also summed up):

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;

private String userName;

@OneToMany
private Collection<Relationship> followings;

}


@Entity
public class Relationship implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;

private User follower;

private User followed;

private boolean accepted;

}
```

My problem is that I'm not sure if it's possible to do this, because I obtain more tables that the two that I need.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 3):

You obtain more tables because you did not make the associations bidirectional. JPA has no way to know that `Relationship.follower` is the other side of the `User.followings` if you don't tell:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "follower")
    private Collection<Relationship> followings;

    // ...
}


@Entity
public class Relationship implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "follower")
    private User follower;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "followed")
    private User followed;

    // ...
}
```

[The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional) of course explains how that works.